# PHP ERROR - Deprecated: Required parameter follows optional parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this error in my coding **Deprecated: Required parameter $message follows optional parameter $level in C:\xampp\htdocs\praktik_1855201019-rest\system\core\Common.php on line 351
.**

this is line 349-363 looks like

```
if ( ! function_exists('log_message'))
{
    function log_message($level = 'error', $message, $php_error = FALSE) **(this one line 351)**
    {
        static $_log;

        if (config_item('log_threshold') == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        $_log =& load_class('Log');
        $_log->write_log($level, $message, $php_error);
    }
}
```

if anyone can help, please leave an answer for my error. thank you so much

Comment: I think it's simply because when you create a function with optional parameters then they have to be put after the mandatory parameters. Here `$message` is mandatory and it is put after `$level` which is optional as it has a default value set to `'error'`.

Comment: That is the first item noted on the [PHP 8 deprecation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.deprecated.php). You can either change the order of the parameters, so that `$message` comes first, or you can give `$message` a default value.

Comment: it's working! thank you so much